# ERROR C2039: 'vector': is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, stdvector

I am new to C++ and I am trying to make a little dungeon crawler game. Currently I have multiple vectors declared in my header files but they seem to give multiple errors. I have tried searching for this problem on StackOverflow but the answers don't really seem to work.

Here is one of my header files: (Hero.h)

```
#pragma once

class Hero {
public:
    Hero();
    std::string name;
    int experience;
    int neededExperience;
    int health;
    int strength;
    int level;
    int speed;
    std::vector<Item> items = std::vector<Item>();
    void levelUp();
private:
};
```

Here is my .cpp file: (Hero.cpp)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include "Hero.h"
#include "Item.h"

Hero::Hero() {

}
void Hero::levelUp()
{

};
```

Like I said I am new to C++ so there might be a lot more wrong with my code than I know. This is just a test.

Below are the errors that are shown in the Error list of Visual Studio 2015:

```
Error   C2039   'vector': is not a member of 'std'  CPPAssessment   hero.h  13  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '<'    CPPAssessment   hero.h  13  
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    CPPAssessment   hero.h  13  
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   hero.h  13
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Include `<vector>` in your **Hero.h** header and consider removing it from your **Hero.cpp** file as mentioned in the comments below.

Comment: Not too sure on this answer. In the cpp file, vector is included before hero.h so it should be okay. What you propose is good advice but, based on OP's information, it wouldn't be a problem here. Having said that, this sort of error is almost always caused by a missing header so it may be that the OP's info is incorrect.

Comment: @paxdiablo Right you are. I am going to delete this answer.

Comment: @paxdiablo We don't know that though. It wouldn't surprise me if stdafx.h includes hero.h, causing it to be parsed before vector.

Comment: stdafx.h doesn't include hero.h

Comment: This is correct, remove `#include <vector>` from your .cpp, and put it in your header file?

Comment: "and remove it from your Hero.cpp file." not strictly necessary but I see why you've added that.

Comment: After some refactoring it works! I have no errors during building. It seems I had to move multiple includes to the .h files such as #include Item.h. Thanks for answering, I will accept this when the 5 minutes pass. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Yes not necessary, but messy, hero.cpp appears to have no explicit use of any vector functionality so no need to include it. It will of course be implicitly included by the use of `class Hero` anyway. </pedanticRant>

Comment: As a general rule, always make the corresponding header file be the *first* header file you include in a cpp file (apart from precompiled header, if you are using them).  That way you make sure you get errors like this when a header file doesn't include all the headers it needs.

Comment: "is it plugged in".  The OP failed to fully describe their situation.  This kind of check is the right thing to do. Don't assume "well, I don't have to, because I did it over there, and that makes it not required".  Check if it is plugged in.

Answer (score 7):

`std::vector<Item> items = std::vector<Item>();` declares a *complete type*.

Therefore the compiler needs to know the *declaration* of `std::vector` at that point (amongst other things, it's required to establish the compile-time evaluable constant `sizeof Hero`). The solution is to `#include <vector>` in the header `hero.h`, **not** the source file.

Answer (score 0):

```
//.h
template<class _Ty>
class std::allocator;
template<class _Ty, class _Alloc = std::allocator<_Ty> >
class std::vector;

//this line in .cpp file. Put it before custom header files.
#include<vector>
```

Tested in vs 2017.
In this way, no header file included in your custom header file.
But not sure why the save way for stack does not work.

For further information, https://github.com/YagaoDirac/snippet-set-for-cpp. And a discord link inside.